# Strange lxml behavior

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I create xml manually and then try to validate it with xsd scheme. Validation doesn't pass at first, but if I convert xml to a string and back - then new xml passes validation.

```
from lxml import etree

xsd = etree.fromstring("""
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="some_namespace">
    <element name="el"></element>
</schema>""")
schema = etree.XMLSchema(xsd)

xml1 = etree.Element('el', nsmap={None: "some_namespace"})
xml2 = etree.fromstring(etree.tostring(xml1))

schema.assertValid(xml2)  # this passes
schema.assertValid(xml1)  # this fails
```

I see that xml1 and xml2 have different tags:

```
print xml1.tag  # --> el
print xml2.tag  # --> {some_namespace}el
```

But why xml1 and xml2 have such a difference? Looks like they should be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you create an `el` element (no namespace):

```
xml1 = etree.Element('el', nsmap={None: "some_namespace"})
```

Using a `nsmap` parameter does not bind the element to a namespace; it just provides a mapping for serialization.

When `etree.tostring(xml1)` is executed, the serialization behaviour "kicks in". When the serialized result has been parsed, `xml2` is an `{some_namespace}el` element instead of `el`.

To make it work, change the line to:

```
xml1 = etree.Element('{some_namespace}el', nsmap={None: "some_namespace"})
```

Comment: Alright, but the fact that original object and object after serialization/deserialization are not logically equal definitely sounds like a bug.

Comment: A conversation in lxml's github here https://github.com/lxml/lxml/pull/136 confirmed that it's not a bug and is intentional. So I consider your answer as right one.