# Why does XML only validate against an XSD when lxml etree.ElementTree is a string?

Tags: python, xsd, lxml, xsd-validation

I have an XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://tempuri.org/me"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/me">

    <xs:element name="B"></xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Using lxml I can create an XML document and validate it against the XSD:

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'sample.xsd')
schema = etree.XMLSchema(file=path)

el = etree.Element('B', nsmap={None: 'http://tempuri.org/me'})
doc = etree.ElementTree(el)

schema.assertValid(doc)
```

However it produces the following error:

```
lxml.etree.DocumentInvalid: Element 'B': No matching global declaration available for the validation root.
```

That error doesn't occur if I convert `doc` to a string and back again it validates:

```
st = etree.tostring(doc)
schema.assertValid(etree.XML(st)) # This validates.
```

What is going on here? Why do I need to convert my etree document to a string and back again to make it validate? How can I prevent that wasteful step?

I'm using Python 3.8 and lxml 4.4.1.

Comment: I have no explanation, but the validation succeeds as expected if the sample element is created like this: `el = etree.Element('{http://tempuri.org/me}B')`.

Comment: @mzjn thank you very much. That solved my technical problem. I'll leave the question open to see if someone can answer why the `nsmap` argument doesn't work as I expect.

Comment: [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22535284/1232660) has some explanation. It also contains [this link to Github](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/pull/136), where the LXML maintainer itself explains the issue.